# Why could anyone wield Callandor after the Dragon touches it?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

Callandor is also known as the "Sword That Cannot Be Touched", and in fact, no one can touch it until the Dragon (Reborn) touches it. After that, *anyone* – at least, among those who can channel – could wield it.

Why is that?

Is it because there are some wards that prevent anyone except the Dragon to touch it? If so, how can the sword recognize the Dragon? And, who put those wards?

*Please use the spoiler tag if the answer to any of the subquestions is found in the second half of the series (book 8 through 14).*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Callandor, one of the most powerful *sa'angreal*, was held deep inside the Stone of Tear; the Heart of the Stone. There were weaves made of both *saidin* and *saidar* meant to prevent anyone from ever touching Callandor.

> “Cautiously, she reached out with the Power, probing at whatever held and shielded the sword. Her probed touched – something – and stopped. She could sense which of the Five Powers had been used here. Air, fire and Spirit. She could trace the intricate weaves made by saidar, set with a strength that amazed her. There were gaps in the weave, spaces her probe should slide through. When she tried, it was like fighting the strongest part of the weave head on. It hit her then that she was trying to force a way through and she let her probe vanish. Half that wall had been woven using saidar, the other half, the part she could not sense or touch, had been made with saidin. That was not it, exactly – the wall was all one piece – but it was close enough”
>
> <sub>(Egwene The Dragon Reborn, Chapter 27).</sub>

When Perrin visits the sword in the Stone he can't get close to the sword

> “Huge columns of polished redstone surrounded the open space where he stood, beneath a domed ceiling fifty paces or more above his head. He and another man as big could not have encircled one of these columns with their arms. The floor was paved with great slabs of pale grey stone, hard yet worn by countless generations of feet. And centered beneath the dome was the reason why all the feet had come to this chamber. A sword, hanging hilt down in the air, apparently without support, seemingly where anyone could reach out and take it. It revolved slowly, as if some breath of air caught it. Yet it was not really a sword. It seemed made of glass, or perhaps crystal, blade and hilt and crossguard, catching such light as there was and shattering it into a thousand glass glitters and flashes. ...A foot from the shining sword, **his hand splayed out against empty air as if it had touched stone**”
>
> <sub>(Perrin, The Dragon Reborn, Chapter 5). Emphasis mine</sub>

However, when Rand fights Ba'alzamon after Moiraine kills Be'lal, he throws himself towards Callandor and seizes the sword  (The Dragon Reborn: Chapter 55). He experiences no resistance in trying to get at the sword.

This means that the weaves were set in place to prevent anyone *except the Dragon* from touching the sword.

Even further, the protection around and inside the Stone of Tear was immense. The Defenders of the Stone's sole purpose was to protect the Stone and prevent anyone, even the Dragon, from gaining access to Callandor.

Once the Dragon touched the sword the weaves were broken, the prophecies were fulfilled.

In The Shadow Rising: Chapter 21, Rand drives the sword into the floor of the Heart of the Stone, further fulfilling the part of The Karaethon Cycle:

> Into the heart he thrusts his sword
>
> into the heart, to hold their hearts
>
> Who draws it out shall follow after
>
> What hand can grasp that fearful blade

and challenging anyone to take the sword if they dare while he is gone. Later, when questioned by Moiraine and Egwene, Rand says he was merely fulfilling the prophecies and tells them about the trap he has set with the One Power should anyone try to take it. ([The Shadow Rising: Chapter 21](https://library.tarvalon.net/index.php?title=The_Shadow_Rising:_Chapter_21))

Path of Daggers content:

> Rand sends Narishma to get the sword, obviously he told Narishma how to unravel the traps Rand placed around the sword.  (Path of Daggers, Chapter 14).

Answer (score 3):

IIRC there was a ward that prevented people from accessing the sword put in place by the last of the ancient Aes Sedai who also used their power to create the Tear as another layer of protection for the sword

the ward probably did not technically recognize the dragon reborn however due to the knowledge the dragon reborn had access to he was able to open the ward

The ward could have been tuned to him in some way as well however how a ward recognizes a person was never explained (its possible theres some kinda DNA soul scan type thing but as I said never explained)